# How to change mount points

Tags: partition, mount

I'm not very deep into this mounting/unmouting thing on Linux, so here goes my question:

With `df -h` I get the following overview:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             323M  306M     0 100% /
tmpfs                 502M     0  502M   0% /lib/init/rw
udev                  497M  116K  497M   1% /dev
tmpfs                 502M     0  502M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda9              47G  181M   44G   1% /home
/dev/sda8             368M   12M  338M   4% /tmp
/dev/sda5             8,3G  1,1G  6,8G  14% /usr
/dev/sda6             2,8G  433M  2,2G  17% /var
```

I'm using this machine as web server where all web related stuff resides under `/srv/`. As this is part of `/` I'm out of disk space here. I saw `/home` having 44G available web space, which is pure nonsense in my case. So I want to have `/home` not as own partition (rather part of `/`), but `/srv` as own partition, grabbing the space consumed by `/home`. So after that `df -h` should look like this (`/home` replaced by `/srv`):

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             323M  306M     0 100% /
tmpfs                 502M     0  502M   0% /lib/init/rw
udev                  497M  116K  497M   1% /dev
tmpfs                 502M     0  502M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda9              47G  181M   44G   1% /srv
/dev/sda8             368M   12M  338M   4% /tmp
/dev/sda5             8,3G  1,1G  6,8G  14% /usr
/dev/sda6             2,8G  433M  2,2G  17% /var
```

What have to do to get here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you have plenty of room in `/home`, move all the stuff from `/srv` into `/home`, then (optionally) move the stuff that was in `/home` to the root partition.

The simplest solution, if you don't mind a few minutes' downtime, is to move `/srv` into the larger partition and symlink it:

```
mv /srv /home
ln -s /home/srv /
```

If you really want to move `/home` to the root partition, then it takes a few renames. I assume there's no directory called `/home/srv` or `/srv/srv`.

```
mv /srv home
mkdir /srv
mount --move /home /srv
mv /srv/acme … /home/
mv /srv/srv/* /srv
rmdir /srv/srv
```

Finally (if you're not using the symbolic link method) edit `/etc/fstab` to change the mount point: on the line that begins with `/dev/sda9 /home`, replace `/home` by `/srv`.

Comment: Thanks - sounds like the best solution to me as I don't have to fiddle around with creating/modifying partitions. Downtime is not a problem as this machine is not yet online.

Answer (score 2):

Before you do anything you're going to have to figure out a place to keep the 180 megabytes of data that /home is currently taking up. I'd recommend repartitioning the current /dev/sda9 into, say, two gigs for `/home` and 42 for `/srv`.

Next up you're going to have to be a little tricky. This is all best accomplished in single user mode so that only root is logged on and you don't run into trouble with someone trying to access `/home` while you're moving it around.

You've got a decent amount of room in /var, so we'll use that as a temporary holding space: 
`mkdir /var/tmp/oldhome`

`cd /home`

`tar -cvf - ./ | ( cd /var/tmp/oldhome && tar -xvf - )

Now we've got `/home` backed up to someplace while we repartition `/dev/sda9` into 2 gigs for `/dev/sda9` and 42 gigs for `/dev/sda10`

Once you've finished repartitioning and creating new filesystems (I'm going to assume you know how to do this) you'll need to edit `/etc/fstab`.

Somewhere in there you'll see a line saying something along the lines of

`/dev/sda9            /home      ext3     defaults    0   2`

Assuming that you've made `/dev/sda9` the smaller of the two partitions, you can leave that line unchanged; you'll just need to add

`/dev/sda10           /srv       ext3     defaults    0   2`

directly underneath.

Once those lines have been added, simply enter

`mount /home ; mount /srv`

and check with `df -h` to make sure both partitions are mounted.

Then replace the data from /home:

`cd /var/tmp/oldhome`

`tar -cvf - ./ | ( cd /home && tar -xvf - )`

Reboot your system in multi-user mode and everything should work.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Say I'd have enough space on `/` for `/home` can't I just switch the mount point from `/dev/sda9 /home ext3 defaults 0 2` to `/dev/sda9 /srv ext3 defaults 0 2` without creating new partions and moving stuff around? Another strange thing: `/home` has only one root-folder which is empty. I don't know why it uses 181M as seen in the output.

Comment: From the outputs, `/` is completely full despite the discrepancy in total and used space - and I'm seeing a similar discrepancy in `/home`. I'd recommend you look //very// carefully at what `/home` actually contains ( `find /home/ -ls` would be a good start. )

Comment: As far as I understood `/home` contains `/srv` (which I could transfer to somewhere else and move it again to `/srv` when it has its own partition). And `/home` really contains only an empty dir `root` and an empty dir `lost+found`. So couldn't I just change `/home` to `/srv` in fstab (after freeing some space in `/`)?

Comment: This is complicated and inefficient! Why move the data around several times? Why bother with `tar` (`cp -a` is actually better at preserving metadata and copying “strange” files)?

Comment: I suppose you could just store it in a tarball rather than unpack each time, but you *are* going to have to move it to a safe location before repartitioning the partition it's currently on.

Answer (score 2):

As a quick but not very beautiful solution, you could remount a directory on one of your less-used disk to some point under `/srv` and move something there to clear a bit of space on `/srv` proper.

Read about `--bind` in `man mount`. It boils down to something like `mount --bind /some/spare/dir /busy/dir/mountpoint`. It works on any modern Linux.

Suppose that you have `/srv/some/stuff`.

- `mkdir /home/offload/some/stuff` — this is on the 44G free space partition
- `mv /srv/some/stuff /srv/some/previous-stuff` — temporarily, free up the name
- `mount --bind /home/offload/some/stuff /srv/some/stuff` — now some/stuff is on another partition!
- `mv /srv/some/previous-stuff/* /srv/some/stuff` — put things back under the original name, free up the space on /srv.